# How to configure client? AWS Elasticsearch request C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, http, elasticsearch

I am new to Amazon Web Services.
I configured domain to use ElasticSearch in AWS(Amazon Web Services) console. Confirured usage of Http Requests.
Went through documantation of creating ElasticSearch client from
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/security.html

```
var response = client.RootNodeInfo(c => c
    .RequestConfiguration(rc => rc
        .BasicAuthentication("UserName", "Password")
    ));
```

Works fine to me (Response is 200)
But when i try to configure authentication credentials like this and pass config to client constructor i need to have "cloudId" i didnt find in at AWS where sould i search for it? or what i have to do?

My client code:

```
BasicAuthenticationCredentials credentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials("UserName", "Password");

var config = new ConnectionSettings("cloudId???", credentials);

var client = new ElasticClient(config);
var response = client.Ping();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did this but a different way. I used the Nuget package AwsSignatureVersion4 and an IAM user with appropriate permissions to the ElasticSearch service.

But basically, use the ImmutableCredentials and just do what I need to do via the REST calls and the C# HttpClient. I find it easier than using the .NET ElasticSearch library. I can then copy/paste back and forth from Kibana.

```
var credentials = new ImmutableCredentials("access_key", "secret_key", null);
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObjOrQuery), Encoding.UTF8);
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var resp = httpClient.PostAsync(es_url, 
    httpContent, 
    regionName: "us-east-1",
    serviceName: "es",
    credentials: credentials).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if(resp.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
{
   //Good to go
}
else
{
  //this gets what ES sent back
  var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  dynamic respJson = JObject.Parse(content.Result());
  //Now you can access stuff by dot and it's dynamic respJson.something
}
```